# Determine whether this limit statement is true or false and why

Tags: calculus, limits

I am having difficulties determining whether or not the following statement is true or false but more specifically, why it would be so.

If $\lim\limits_{x \to 2} f(x) = f(2)$, then $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}{h}$ exists.

Comment: It does not.  Imagine a triangle wave which has a peak at $x = 2$.  The value of the function exists there but is not differentiable there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The statement is equivalent to "If $f(x)$ is continuous at $2$, then it is differentiable at $2$."

Answer (score 1):

Counter-example:

$$f(x) = \sqrt{x - 2}$$

Answer (score 1):

This statement is

> FALSE

because

> we can find numerous counter-examples such as $f(x) = |x-2|$. Clearly f(x) approaches f(2)=0 as x approaches 2, but the function is not differentiable at that point.

It is nice to note, however, that

> the converse is true - i.e. that differentiability implies continuity.